# Size and space between subplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subplot

I have a subplot as following

```
mydata <- data.frame(side1=rep(LETTERS[1:3],3,each=9),side2=rep(LETTERS[1:3],9,each=3),widget=rep(c("X","Y","Z"),9*3),size=rep(1/3,9*3),strength=runif(27,-1,1))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x="",y = size, fill = strength, width = widget)) +
geom_bar(width = 1) + 
facet_grid(side1 ~ side2) +
scale_x_discrete("",breaks=NULL) + 
coord_polar("y") + scale_fill_gradient2() +
scale_y_continuous("",breaks=NULL)+
theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank())
```

I would like reduce the space between each subplot as well as their size. since I am after making 100x100 subplot. So being close to each other and also the size is really important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce the space between subplots use `panel.margin=` in `theme()`, for example

```
library(grid)    
+theme(panel.margin=unit(0,"cm"))
```

To set `unit()` you should use library `grid`.

The size of each subplot will depend on size of tho whole plot. You can set the size of whole plot using `ggsave()` function to save plot in some of formats (pdf, jpg) and setting `width=` and `height=` of whole plot.